# Python - Importing all files within a date range from a folder

Tags: python, python-import, glob

I have a folder called C:\Flows in which I have multiple files in the format of `20190101_Flows.csv` for all the days of this year.

I want to import a file for each day perform operations on it and then save the file. However, I'm stuck at it.

So far, I have  written the code below to get the files. But I am stuck after that.

```
from datetime import date

from datetime import datetime, timedelta
import glob
from os import path

DATE_FORMAT = "%Y%m%d"


pathDir = r'C:/Flows/'

dateStart = "20190301"
dateEnd = "20190305"

start_date = datetime.strptime(dateStart, DATE_FORMAT).date()
end_date = datetime.strptime(dateEnd, DATE_FORMAT).date()

delta_one_day = timedelta(days=1)

date = start_date
while date <= end_date:
    data_folder = path.join(pathDir)
    if path.isdir(data_folder):
        for filename in glob(os.path.join(data_folder, "*_Flows.csv")):

#this is where i would like to perform the operations on the file imported

           df['code']=df[df.columns[1]].astype(str).str[0:3]
            df['bmunit']=df[df.columns[1]].astype(str).str[4:]
            df['checko']=df.iloc[:,2:50].sum(axis=1)
            print filename
    date += delta_one_day
```

Comment: Have you tried using string formating rather than date ? Might be easier to deal with ?

Comment: What's the error?